# Fade In Fade Out Animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

Here is some code I struggle with for a while.

If you start the fade in animation, the label text fades in.
If I start the fade out animation the the label text fades out.

When I start the `startFade` method, only fade out is shown. How can I wait for the `fadeIn` method to finish visually before starting the `fadeOut` method.

```
-(IBAction)startFade:(id)sender{
    [self fadeIn];
    [self fadeOut];
}

-(IBAction)fadeIn:(id)sender{
    [self fadeIn];
}

-(IBAction)fadeOut:(id)sender{
[self fadeOut];
}

-(void) fadeIn{
    [_label setAlpha:0];
    [UILabel beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UILabel setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [_label setAlpha:1];
    [UILabel commitAnimations];
}

-(void) fadeOut{
    [UILabel beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UILabel setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [_label setAlpha:0];
    [UILabel commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: have you tried the block-based animations yet?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

When you call the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods back to back like you're doing, the code is run instantaneously, so you'll only see animation from the last method called. UIView block based animation provides a completion handler, which seems to be exactly what you're looking for. So your code might looks something like this:

```
-(IBAction)startFade:(id)sender {

    [_label setAlpha:0.0f];        

    //fade in
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

        [_label setAlpha:1.0f];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //fade out
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

            [_label setAlpha:0.0f];

        } completion:nil];

    }];
}
```

Swift:

```
@IBAction func startFade(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    label.alpha = 0.0

    // fade in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { 
        label.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (finished) in
        // fade out
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            label.alpha = 0.0
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and where is the second half of the fade-effect?

Comment: I always forget to do that. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 34):

that does the job for you (the `_label` is your label);

```
- (IBAction)startFade:(id)sender {
    [_label setAlpha:0.f];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [_label setAlpha:1.f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [_label setAlpha:0.f];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Can be simplified by adding UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse to the options of the first animation, i.e. UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse, and just having completion:nil instead of another animation.

Comment: @BjørnEgil, if there is no such a goal which is about changing any attribute of the `UILabel` between half way, that could also work as well.

Comment: yeah, but that was not part of the question. It was just how to fade in and out.

Comment: @BjørnEgil, the answer tries to be as generic as it is possible for another users or developers, who may try to re-use the idea.

Answer (score 7):

Generic answer : You can use this method to apply animation to any UIView object .
First create an extension of UIView class . Create a separate swift file and write the code like this

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    func fadeIn() {
        //Swift 2
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)

        //Swift 3, 4, 5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }


    func fadeOut() {
        //Swift 2
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)

        //Swift 3, 4, 5
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Here self refers to any UIView you refer to . You can use buttons, labels etc to call these 2 methods .

Then in any other swift class you can call fadeIn() and fadeOut() like this :

```
self.yourUIObject.fadeIn()
self.yourUIObject.fadeOut()
```

This gives the desired effect of animation to any UIObject .

Answer (score 6):

Try this..

// Fade Out

```
 -(void)fadeOut:(UIView*)viewToDissolve withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration   andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
{
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];

// wait for time before begin
[UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];

// druation of animation
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
viewToDissolve.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

//   Fade In

```
-(void) fadeIn:(UIView*)viewToFadeIn withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait

{
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade In" context:nil];

// wait for time before begin
[UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];

    // druation of animation
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
viewToFadeIn.alpha = 1;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

//  Fade in from fade out

```
-(void) fadeInFromFadeOut: (UIView*)viewToFadeIn withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    viewToFadeIn.hidden=NO;
    [self fadeOut:viewToFadeIn withDuration:1 andWait:0];
    [self fadeIn:viewToFadeIn withDuration:duration andWait:0];

}
```

// Button operation

```
-(void) buttonClicked :(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"Button clicked");

// Each button is given a tag
int tag = ((UIButton*)sender).tag;
if (tag ==1)
{
    sprite.alpha  =1;
    [self fadeOut : sprite withDuration: 10 andWait : 1 ];
}
else if (tag ==2)
{
    sprite.alpha  =0;
    [self fadeIn : sprite withDuration: 3 andWait : 1 ];
}
else
{
    [self fadeInFromFadeOut:sprite withDuration:10];
}
}
```

View this [link](http://www.developerfeed.com/ios-fade-and-fade-out-view-effects) to download sample..

Refer this [link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/fade-transition-fade-images-in-and-out.html).

Happy to share with you..:-)

Comment: Cool Stuff;Everybody!! Checked out a lot of your Ideas and approaches. Helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this (check possible parameters values and similar methods here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:delay
                    options:option 
                 animations:^{
                     //fade in here (changing alpha of UILabel component)
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    if(finished){
                      //start a fade out here when previous animation is finished (changing alpha of UILabel component)
                 }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @holex's answer, but simplified a bit (as commented):

```
- (IBAction)startFade:(id)sender {
   [_label setAlpha:0.f];

   [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f 
                         delay:0.f 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                             | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse 
                    animations:^{
                                  [_label setAlpha:1.f];
                                } 
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**
If you need just one pulse when clicking the button, use that:

```
@IBAction func didPressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.someView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: [.curveEaseInOut, .autoreverse],
                       animations: {
                        self.someView.alpha = 1
        },
                       completion: { _ in
                        self.someView.alpha = 0
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version of iPhoneDeveloper's answer:

```
extension UIView {
    
    func fadeIn() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func fadeOut() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion]
```

and add the `fadeOut` call to the `completion` block. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) might help answer any questions you have.

If you can't use the block version for some reason, then you'll have to set a delegate (`[UIView setAnimationDelegate:(id)delegate]`) and a selector with (`[UIView  setAnimationDidStopSelector:]`) that the delegate will respond to.

Again, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDelegate%3a) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

My task was to make a label fade out. And then fade in with changed text. The solution was:

```
    -(void)performAnimationOnHistoryButtonLabelUpdatingTextTo:(NSString *)text
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
        [self.historyButtonLabel setAlpha:0.0f];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.historyButtonLabel.text = text;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
            [self.historyButtonLabel setAlpha:1.0f];
        } completion:nil];

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
labelAnimate = (UILabel*) [self.view viewWithTag:101];
btnTapMe = (UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:100];
[btnTapMe addTarget:self action:@selector(startAnimating:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//////////////

-(void) startAnimating:(UIButton*)button {
    [labelAnimate setAlpha:0.0];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.8 target:self selector:@selector(continuousEaseInOut) userInfo:button repeats:YES];
}

-(void) continuousFadeInOut {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [labelAnimate setAlpha:1.0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [labelAnimate setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you use a generic implementation so you can reuse the code whenever you need the fade effect again.

You should create an `UIView` extension:

`UIView+Animations.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIView (Animations)

- (void)fadeInWithCompletion:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL finished))completion;
- (void)fadeOutWithCompletion:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL finished))completion;;

@end
```

`UIView+Animations.m`

```
#import "UIView+Animations.h"

@implementation UIView (Animations)

- (void)fadeInWithCompletion:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL finished))completion {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        [self setAlpha:1];
    } completion:completion];
}

- (void)fadeOutWithCompletion:(void (^ __nullable)(BOOL finished))completion {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        [self setAlpha:0];
    } completion:completion];
}

@end
```

So, you only have to import the new file to your class or inside your `Prefix.pch` and use it like this:

```
[_label fadeOutWithCompletion:^(BOOL finished) {
   [_label fadeInWithCompletion:nil];
}];
```

Note that you could also use `nil` as the completion parameter when you have nothing else to do after completion.

I also recommend you do not parameterize the duration to keep a pattern through you entire application.

This implementation can be used in the future for `UIButton`, `UILabel`, `UITextField`... Well, any class derived from `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

The fade in and fade out animations can be combined using `UIView.animate(withDuration: animations:)`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
            myView.alpha = 0.75
            myView.alpha = 1.0
        })
```