# UITableView Custom Selection Size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get a similar `UITableView` selection look as shown on the 'Upcoming cell' below. I am achieving the rounded corners but am unsure how to get the BKG to not be the 100% width of the `tableView`. The current code I have is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "folderCell", for: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    return cell
}
```

EDIT: All solutions below are still not solving this issue... 14/11/19

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a view to the contentView with it's width say 90% of cell , then change it's background when selected/deselected inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.someView.backgroundColor = indexPath.row == selectedRow ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.green
```

Where

```
var selectedRow:Int?
```

Inside `didSelectRowAt`

```
selectedRow = indexPath.row
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: it's not a good way it reloads whole table data every time you can do it with just setSelected override method also.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani cells are dequeued , logic of coloring should be inside `cellForRowAt` ,  it could also be a matter of reloading the old selected row if exists/visible and the new one

Answer (score 0):

Add Background View inside `UITableView` cell like this :

[image]

**UITableViewCell**

```
class FolderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var selectedView: UIView!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        selectedView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.red : UIColor.clear // change selected color here
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be working for me. Selected is only getting triggered on touch off...

Comment: @mink23 it's working fine, please verify once again.

Comment: Yep, using your code it wasn't working at all so I modified to:     override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected == true {
            selectionBKG.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            selectionBKG.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }

Comment: Even with this it is only changing colour on lift of tap... not on tap. I'm using iOS 13...

Comment: Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: @mink23 you just need to check view hierarchy in **UITableViewCell** and make sure connect IBOutlet of background view as you can see in my answer of blue view and just simply change in setSelected method that's it remove all other code and all things that you have done before and check it's working fine dear.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra UIView to your FolderTableViewCell with your choice of size and colour for selection and then make it hidden by default, make it visible in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and hidden in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Is there a way to have it fade in and out with this method?

Comment: Yes, Instead just hiding and showing the view you can do animation to your custom view. check this ink for more ideas on fade in fade out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891614/fade-in-fade-out-animation

Comment: I tried this but am getting the error 'Outlets can not be connected to repeating content'. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a table view cell subclass and set it as the class of the prototype. Add the outlets to that class and connect them. Now when you configure the cell you can access the outlets.

Comment: I have that setup now. Though I can't access didSelectRowAtIndexPath from the UITableViewCell class...

Answer (score 0):

Give clear color to tableview.
and leave the Leading and Trailing spacing for tableview from superview. 
Give background color to superView.
Simple hack to save your time